# Linkedin Profile API

Tags: linkedin-api

We want to integrate our app with Linkedin. Our Story is that users sign-in with Linkedin and give access to our app to get profile information from Linkedin and merge local information.
Now we create an app for integration but we just have r_liteprofile permission and this access is not satisfactory because we need complete user profile information.

I read Microsoft technical documents and saw this sentence `Access to r_fullprofile is now closed. Consider requesting access to the r_liteprofile instead.`
So what is your alternative way to get full profile information?